# Photoshop Vectors turned into raster images automatically

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, pixel, raster, creative-cloud

Sorry if this has been done before. I just got Creative Cloud, have worked on older versions of Photoshop before. Every time I try to do anything vector based in Ps CC, be it Text, Pen Tool or creating simple Shapes, Ps shows them pixellated and as if they were rasterised whilst showing it as Shape layer, with option to rasterise still selectable. With type, anti-aliasing is on. Am running Illustrator too and there is no problem with my screen representing vector based shapes crisp and clear. 
When I print text from Ps, it comes out pixellated.
When I save it out as e.g. jpg, it is blurry and pixellated. 
Help please!

Is there something in Ps like the Pixel Preview Setting in Illustrator that I may have switched on accidentally without knowing?

Comment: Photoshop is, in itself, raster images. The vector shapes are merely used to support raster output. Everything in Photoshop is mapped to individual pixels.

Answer (score 3):

**Your monitor uses pixels to display everything.** There's no such thing as an image on your screen which is *not* represented by pixels.

The amount of pixel visibility depends greatly upon your monitors pixel density.

Illustrator will display content (in pixels for the monitor) at the highest possible pixel density for your monitor. This is regardless of zoom level and there are no PPI settings for Illustrator so everything is always "maximum pixel density".

Photoshop will display content based upon the monitor pixel density *and* the documents ppi settings. *Whichever is smaller.* If you have a low resolution (ppi) image in Photoshop, then the display is going to make pixels more apparent. Zooming in on an image in Photoshop will further exaggerate the screen display of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving a thread from the dead here just in case anyone else stumbles across it - when you make a new document in PS, you can set the size in pixels and the resolution - for print increase that from 72 to 300.

Or in an existing document, increase the image size ('Image'-> 'Image Size')

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot? How do you get rid of pixelised images?